# Group PostGIS table-rows where geometries are close

Tags: postgis, postgresql, clustering, spatial-cluster

In OSM there are often e.g. lines (paths) with the same name but different OSM-IDs. Right next to each other, so basically the same thing, but just different objects with no real relation to each other.

So in my table it would look like the following

```
osm_id    name      highway    geometry
---------------------------------------------
1         trail_1   path       <some-line>
2         trail_1   path       <some-line>
3         trail_2   path       <some-line>
```

I looked at `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` and that looks promising?!? I am just too bad with SQL to fully understand it.

So I'd like to group my lines by name, cluster them, look at each cluster -> take the metadata (osm_id, name, highway,... ) of one of them and also the combined geometry (`ST_LineMerge` or `ST_Union`?!?) of all of them -> Save as a new entry in a separate table.

So from my example in a separate table I only want to have TWO entries left:

```
osm_id    name      highway    geometry
---------------------------------------------
1         trail_1   path       <some-merged-line>
3         trail_2   path       <some-line>
```

I am not really sure yet how to tackle the whole thing. Can I do that solely in PostGIS?